# Why is wordpress outputting menu html with no space between <li> tags

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using `display:inline-block;` and `text-align:justify;` to centre my main navigation. The new wordpress 4.4 update seems to be outputting html with no white space between the main `<li>` tags. Has anyone else found this and how to stop it?

E.g. one of my sites - http://melodywheels.com.au - I've hacked it for now to get the menu centred but it was working much better before wordpress changed the output.

Instead of outputting

```
<ul>
<li>Menu item</li>
<li>Menu item</li>
<li>Menu item</li>
</ul>
```

it is outputting

```
<ul>
<li>Menu item</li></li>Menu Item</li><li>Menu item</li>
</ul>
```

Which obviously messes with the whole inline-block justified menu.

I can't see anyway to change this and searching online only seems to bring up responses for doing the opposite - removing white space between inline-block items.

Thanks!

**FIX**

Add this to your functions.php file

```
// Fix stupid wordpress 4.4 'feature' that breaks justified menus

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'filter_menu_items');
function filter_menu_items($menu_items){
  return str_replace('</li><li', "</li> <li", $menu_items);
}
```

Comment: You can always use a custom `menu-walker` to render your menus...

Comment: Try to add width: 100%; to your li in css. e.g. `ul li{ width: 100%;}`

Comment: `li::after {content:' '}`

Comment: @dingo_d I'll have a look at that, thanks. Looks quite complex for a problem that was only introduced in wordpress 4.4 - might be easier just to use flexbox or something else to display the menu

Comment: @KeesSonnema that will mess with the rest of the css as the reason to use display inline-block and justified is that so they are evenly spaced

Comment: @MrLister I'll try that although It's not really white space in the DOM that I need, it's actual white space in the outputted HMTL

Comment: @PatrickHazard You're right. This is a tricky problem. My bet is on Flexbox. But that's not really supported in older browsers. But you could always fall back to older IE browsers with the hack you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution with Dave Bloom's help.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-44-update-breaks-wp_nav_menu-layout

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for that. I actually went to submit a bug to wordpress about the 4.4 release but while submitting I found out that this bug is actually a 'feature' that was submitted to the wordpress core to 'fix' other problems where `display:inline-block;` had the space between elements. If that was a 'fix' it's unlikely they'll want to revert back to the more logical method they previously had!